# Can 'slips' be used here?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

Tim races down the hallway, followed by Tony. Tony raises his gun and fires, but Tim **slips** around a corner.

Is **slips** a natural choice of verb here or can it only be used if Tim made it around the corner unseen?

From dictionary: *go or move quietly or quickly, without attracting notice.*

Answer (score 2):

Yes, "slip" in this sense has been used since the 1400s

OED:

> **2. To pass or go lightly or quietly; to move quickly and softly, without attracting notice; to glide or steal.** *Used with various adverbs and prepositions.*
>
> 1863   B. Taylor Hannah Thurston i. 17   *Mrs. Waldo slipped to the door and peeped in.*
>
> 1865   J. Hatton Bitter Sweets iii   *I'll slip up with some bread and milk for you.*